# Arquillian Wildfly remote domain tests: Not working: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can not deploy directly from a Domain Controller

Tags: jboss, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-10

I am trying to run Arquillian tests on a remote JBoss EAP 7 in domain mode. My config is in arquillian.xml:

```html
 <group qualifier="jbosseap-integration-domain" default="false">
        <container qualifier="jbosseap-integration-int1" default="false">
            <protocol type="Servlet 3.0">
                <property name="executionType">REMOTE</property>
            </protocol>
            <configuration>
                <property name="managementAddress">XXXXXXXXX1.xarxa.interna</property>
                <property name="managementPort">9999</property>
                <property name="username">XXXXX</property>
                <property name="password">XXXXXX</property>
                <property name="serverGroupOperationTimeoutInSeconds">3600</property>
                <property name="serverOperationTimeoutInSeconds">3600</property>
            </configuration>
        </container>
         <container qualifier="jbosseap-integration-int2" default="false">
            <protocol type="Servlet 3.0">
                <property name="executionType">REMOTE</property>
            </protocol>
            <configuration>
                <property name="managementAddress">XXXXXX2.xarxa.interna</property>
                <property name="managementPort">9999</property>
                <property name="username">XXXXX</property>
                <property name="password">XXXXXX</property>
                <property name="serverGroupOperationTimeoutInSeconds">3600</property>
                <property name="serverOperationTimeoutInSeconds">3600</property>

            </configuration>
        </container>
    </group>
```

And in maven:

```html
<profile>
   <id>int</id>
   <properties>
    <cdi.project.stage>Staging</cdi.project.stage>
    <jsf.project.stage>Production</jsf.project.stage>
    <!-- Arquillian config -->
    <arquillian.container.name>jbosseap-integration-domain</arquillian.container.name>
    <!-- Logging -->
    <logging.level>INFO</logging.level>
    <!--Environment name for war name generation and resource filtering -->
    <environmentName>int</environmentName>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
    <!-- The integration tests are done on the integration standalone server, 
     as configured in arquillian.xml -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-domain-remote</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
    <plugins>
     <!-- JBoss AS Domain deploy configuration, on integration server group. 
      This server is used by the final user to make it's manual tests, so the DATA 
      MUST BE PRESERVED at all costs. -->
     <plugin>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
       <filename>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx-${project.version}-${environmentName}.war</filename>
       <hostname>XXXXXXX.xarxa.interna</hostname>
       <port>9999</port>
       <username>XXXX</username>
       <password>XXXXXXXXXXXx</password>
       <domain>
        <server-groups>
         <server-group>servergroup-integracio</server-group>
        </server-groups>
        <profiles>
         <profile>full-ha-int</profile>
        </profiles>
       </domain>
      </configuration>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
  </profile>
```

I get the following error: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can not deploy directly from a Domain Controller

Comment: Can you try version 2.0.0.Final? There were some issues in 1.x with domain deployments.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the reply. I can not find wildfly-arquillian-container-domain-remote version 2.0.0.Final. Thanks

Comment: Hi James, managed to get version 2.0.0.Final, nou I ghet the following error: Could not determine the server-group to deploy the archive to.

Comment: With 2.0 there was a new annotation introduced for domain, `@TargetsServerGroup("main-server-group")`. I think there was a way to use `@TargetsContainer` too, but I can't recall the syntax off the top of my head.

Comment: James, not working anyway. No documentation is provided for this use case. Any other clue?

Comment: Sorry I don't have much information on it. I'll have to see where the documentation for it is located and likely update it. The best I currently have is the test example in the test suite https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-arquillian/blob/master/container-managed-domain/src/test/java/org/jboss/as/arquillian/container/domain/managed/test/ManagedDomainTestCase.java#L35.